# NextCloud Version Control

Tags: windows, linux, security, version-control, nextcloud

I plan on hosting a [NextCloud](https://nextcloud.com/) instance via a Web-Server at work (due to high PC specs, "always online", and well...free power) to house all my Powershell, Bash and other documentation and scripts for access from home.

Whilst I can use the Web-Browser to download and edit files, I would prefer to implement [their desktop clients](https://nextcloud.com/install/#install-clients) for ease of use. Whilst I am not sure if my needs are met by this client, I am more looking for an add-on or script to go in unison with this client,but am happy to use another tool.

For reference, it is:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:nextcloud-devs/client 
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nextcloud-client
```

(Side Note: If you fail to enter the server's DNS or IP the first time, I suspect you need to clear the program cache and open again).

What I am ideally looking for would be to restrict user access (which is a no-brainer, plus limiting IP Address Connections) but also allow concurrent editing of files and version control. Essentially, the process will be:

1. User X downloads a copy of `deleteyourdomain.ps1` and tests on their instance;
2. User X then re-uploads the file, and makes the relevant changes in Planner to list the stage they're at (we're also thinking of implementing some other form of notation)
3. User Y will then perform some work on the same file(s)

What I am looking for here is some form of notification based on rules. For my instance, rules such as:

1. User X has downloaded this file >X Time frame ago and may still be editing it;
2. User X has already uploaded a newer file that you've not downloaded or;
3. User X has made changes since you've last downloaded the files (albeit not re-downloaded or uploaded) and has notes

Because the work being performed will be a decentralised instance, multiple users will login and edit the files at their discretion, and incidentally override other people's work (albeit we may have *local* copies).

Useful articles I am to read and see how they have been implemented:

- [Version Control, Nextcloud 9 Manual](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/9/user_manual/files/version_control.html)
- [External Storage Support](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/13/admin_manual/configuration_files/external_storage_configuration_gui.html#storage-configuration)
- [Transaction File Locking](https://docs.nextcloud.com/server/13/admin_manual/configuration_files/files_locking_transactional.html)

In terms of **Requirements** there are not many requirements (outside the desktop client); we're simply after a nifty file-version control process for the documents stored.

In terms of **Wants**:

- Free, and open source;
- Run on Windows, Linux and OSX and;
- Have stable support/documentation

The client ideally supports encryption by default, of course.
I am happy to pay a **single** payment of $0-75.00AUD for this product should it come with a Support Agreement.

Comment: In terms of [Store](https://apps.nextcloud.com/) several applications are of use. Apps such as [File Access Control](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/files_accesscontrol) and [Activities for Shared File Downloads](https://apps.nextcloud.com/apps/files_downloadactivity) may be of use here.

Comment: Tags that may be of relevance here are [File-Sync](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/file-synchronization) and [Syncronization](https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/synchronization) albeit I am not able to find any questions that relate to this.